# Using GhostScript to export PNGs at fixed size

Tags: png, ghostscript, eps

We have many square EPS images, which we would like to export via script to PNG at very specific formats/sizes, namely

- 8192x8192, greyscale, no alpha, *no anti-aliasing*
- 2048x2048,greyscale, no alpha, anti-aliased.

We have had no luck scripting the "professional" tools Photoshop or Illustrator to do this (although we can do so through the UI, their weak scripting support does not give control over alpha or precise image export size, so we either always get alpha in the large images, or we sometimes get slightly inaccurate image sizes which breaks subsequent algorithms.)

Our first attempt at doing the high resolution version of this was:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pnggray -o cover.png -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=8192 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=8192 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=1 -dPDFFitPage=true cover.eps
```

However, this does not seem to resize the image to fill the box as expected.

Is there a way, given a square EPS, to get Ghostscript to do what we want?

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example EPS and describe what parts you want filled in the PNG or also post a properly output PNG. Imagemagick may help make this easier, though it relies upon Ghostscript to do the work.

Comment: I could but all the images I'm using are subject to copyright, so I need to make a synthetic image and I need to mess around hosting the EPS file somewhere "properly" public, i.e. not just dropbox. The main part of the problem deals with exporting an image at a known output canvas size (2048x2048) as opposed to a known *resolution* like 72dpi, which obviously produces different PNG sizes dependent upon the image's physical size (which I don't care about as this is not for print.) Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In Imagemagick, I would specify a larger density than you need, then resize to the size you want. That produces very good quality result, though may take longer than you want. Something like: `convert -density 288 image.eps -resize WxH image.png` in IM 6 and replace convert with magick for IM 7. This assumes that -density 288 makes a raster image several times as large as your desired WxH.

Comment: That's not a valid solution as I want precise hinting (especially in the case of the non-anti-aliased 16k-sq image, which I want to be more or less binary. Plus, "much higher than 8192-sq" becomes enormous quickly (especially as in some cases we use 16384-sq or 24k-sq. I have a variety of options already in various tools for "render at random high resolution and downsample to precise size". I want to render at a precise size. I don't really understand why all bitmap rasterizers can't do this and instead focus on physical dimensions, when bitmaps are dimensionless and a pixel is just a pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not accidentally specify PDFFitPage in the command line above. Specify EPSFitPage when dealing with EPS files. PDFFitPage will silently do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with EPS files is that they do not request a media size. That's because EPS files are intended to be included in other PostScript programs, so they need to be resized by the application generating the PostScript.

To that end, EPS files include comments (which are ignored by PostScript interpreters) which define the BoundingBox of the EPS. An application which places EPS can quickly scan the EPS to find this information, then it sets the CTM appropriately in the final PostScript program it is creating and inserts the content of the EPS.

The `FitPage` switch in Ghostscript relies on having a known media size (and you should set `-dFIXEDMEDIA` when using this) and a requested media size, figuring out what scale factor to apply to the request in order to make it fit the actual size, and setting up the CTM to apply that scaling.

If you don't ever get a media size request (which you won't with an EPS) then no scaling will take place.

Now Ghostscript **does** have a different switch, `EPSCrop` which picks up the comments from the EPS and uses that to set the media size (Ghostscript has mechanisms to permit processing of comments for this reason, amongst others). You could implement a similar mechanism to pick up the BoundingBox comments, and scale the EPS so that it fits a desired target media size.

I could probably knock something up, but I'd have to mess around creating an example file to work from.....